# How to parallelize a heavy process on a String

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to parallelize a process in a string to make it more faster, this process is made by more than method.

```
String s = process1(sourcepage);
                s= process2(s);
                s= process3(s);
                s= process4(s);
                s= process5(s);
                s= process6(s);
                s= process7(s);
                s= process8(s);
                s= process9(s);
                s= process10(s);
                s= process11(s);
```

How can I parallelize this process to make it more faster, knowing that `process(n)` performed on the result of `process(n-1)`.

Assuming the String is HTML and the `process(i)` is a removal of a tag (portion of code) in the HTML.

So for example we want to remove the footer and the `<div =class="something">` and the `<h1>` from the HTML.

Thank you so much

Comment: You cannot parallelize if N depends on N-1

Comment: Are each of the steps dependent on each other?  That is, can the steps be done in any order, so long as they are done?  If not, then your only option would be course grain parallelizaiton.  If the steps are independent, then you might be able to do some multithreaded programming to speed things up.

Comment: the order is not important, but we have to perform all the process in the same String.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter, then do some research on Java thread executor services.

Comment: Assuming this is to sanitize a `String`, you can't run this in parallel simply because you might loose some modification. You would need to be able to merge multiple `String` to see what changed between two process (dangerous and might never work if one process need the update of the previous one). But depending on the treatment, you could split the process to run these in parallel. on substring.

Comment: @AxelH That won't work either, if the substring split happens to cut a "dangerous token" apart.

Comment: Generally this cannot be done. However if you show a [mcve] (what those processes are) we may be able to help, by providing you a better (parallelizable) algorithm.

Comment: Assuming that the String is a big HTML and the process are the removal of tags (script, label, ul, li, footer ..) so we have to execute all the removals in the same html string. the output should be the without the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know some process doesn't modifiy `s`, parallelize those !

---

Assuming this is modify the parameter, you can't run this in parallel simply because you might loose some modification.

Let's say you have three process :

- p1 : trim the `String`
- p2 : replace every `${string}` with the value in `Map<String, String>`
- p3 : replace some character to be safe.

Run these in parallel, each will update a different `String`, and the last one will give you a result. Now you could get each `String` and try to merge these by checking what changed but this would become complicated to do.

Notice that if `p3` runs before `p2`, you could end up with some character that need to be removed.

I have two suggestion :

- parallelize the logic in a process.
- Split the `String` to be processed separatly (in parallel) and the merge the result together. This need to be splitted where this is "safe".

The second solution become complicated if this is to read a structure text (like a JSON or XML) but could be resolve by parsing the format correctly then processing each "node".

Both solution can be done or can be impossible based on those processing. That's up to you to choose.

EDIT:

> Assuming the String is an 'HTML' and the process(i) is a removal of a tag (portion of code) in the HTML.

Then you should be able to split your "HTML" to process each tag separately. Using an XML library, this would be quite safe.

Comment: Well, if you think of the string as a stream of characters, then this could be made into a pipeline, in which process p2 works on the characters that have already been processed by p1, p3 on the characters that have already been processed by p2 and so on, allowing some parallelism. The question really needs an MCVE.

Comment: Yeah, that would fall in my second solution (with some finer granularity) to split the value for multi processing. I totally agree that this requires a MCVE @RealSkeptic, I try to kept this generic.

Comment: @RealSkeptic  +1 I made a small MCVE to unterstand well my request. Thank you guys